# How to open add-in automatically on opening excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to know how I can have a workbook automatically open an add-in? The problem is after I create the workbook in code -- call it "A.xlsx" -- I want to add code to it (on creation) that will open the Excel add-in "B.xlam". How do I do this? Creating the workbook is no problem; that part is sorted, and I just want to add the code to that workbook, so that every time it opens it must open the add-in "B.xlam" with it.

Comment: the add-in file is a member of the Excel `Application`, usuallly, and not something that gets "opened" with a workbook.  Can you clarify what you want? Why not just install the add-in?  Otherwise, look in to adding some code to the `A.xlsx` event for `Workbook_Open`.

Comment: @DavidZemens how do i install the add-in? btw the add-in is basically just an excel workbook with macros, saved as a ".xlam". adding code to the `A.xlsx` `workbook_Open` event is exactly what i want to do. so i basically want to change/add code on another workbook. how do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

From the Developer Ribbon, click Add-Ins,

[image]

then click Browse, then navigate to the location of the desired add-in file, then select it, and make sure the checkbox is selected for it.

[image]

Alternatively, store the code in PERSONAL.XLS/PERSONAL.XLSB, and these macros/functions will be available to all open workbooks.

If you're somehow asking how to programmatically insert code in to new workbook files, I'm afraid you're out of your element.  If you don't know about the `Workbook_Open` event, nor how to manage your Add-Ins, etc., manipulating the VBE is a pretty high-level operation, and I would not be able to help you with that.

**Update from comments**

Here is one method that will export VB Components to a specific path, example also includes code to import modules from path to a workbook.  You should be able to adapt this to your purposes.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm

**If you have specific problems implementing this solution, please post as a new question.**

Comment: thank you for explaining installing addins. i do know about the `Worksheet_Open` event,work with it all the time, what i dont know is how to change that event from another workbook. this is something that i have not done yet, and as for installing the add on, i dont want it present in every workbook my client opens, just the one specific one i created in a macro on another workbook.

Comment: So you essentially want to insert code in to the new workbook. I'll update to give you a link that will be macros capable of exporting all VB components from one workbook, and then importing to another.

Comment: Or, consider creating an XLSB template file, which includes the macros/etc., then when you "create" the new file, just create it from the template instead of creating it as an XLSM and importing the code modules.  That would probably be easier, although I have not tried it.

Comment: Just to update you, i was able to change the vba code in another workbook, here is the code i used 
`Private mCodeMod As CodeModule

Sub insertcode()
Dim VBComp As VBComponent


Set VBComp = Workbooks("hello.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)

Set mCodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

With mCodeMod
.InsertLines Line:=1, String:="sub hello()"
.InsertLines Line:=2, String:="end sub"
End With

End Sub`

Obviously this was just for me to see how to do it, and the workbook`hello.xlsm` has to be open.

Comment: Yes it's not terribly difficult but it is a higher level function, and you're going to run in to permissions/privacy issues, if you're trying to do this on client machines.  Just a warning :)